# how to capture error json records coming from event hub to azure stream analytics

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

all, Can anybody help me with the solution for capturing the malformed json coming from event hub to azure stream analytics.

My use case is : I am getting json records on the event hub i.e. input is event hub -> parsing the json in Azure Stream analytics -> placing the parsed data in azure SQL DWH.

Now whenever the malformed json comes on the eventhub the ASA drops that event and parses only the correct json. I need to capture those malformed event ans report it to the Source application. Could you please let me know how to do this ?

Thanks,
Aditya

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-troubleshoot-input?view=azurermps-6.13.0#malformed-input-events-causes-deserialization-errors), seems that it can meet your needs.

When a Stream Analytics job receives a malformed message from an input, it drops the message and notifies you with a warning. Then follow this [What caused the deserialization error](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-troubleshoot-input?view=azurermps-6.13.0#what-caused-the-deserialization-error) to  find the JSON data with the incorrect format.